# How to properly use a referenceJar in Xamarin Android Project?

Tags: xamarin, jar, xamarin.android

I have a .aar file that contains a SDK, it needs the gson library to work, so i added the gson.jar file into the project as a ReferenceJar, but it cannot find the reference.

I've already tried to extract the jar from the aar, and use one as InputJar and the gson jar as ReferenceJar, it did not work.
In this case the java code spits this error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;`

I've tried to create a separate project that contains only the gson file as a InputJar and use it as a dependency on the other project.
In this case the gson project does not compile, VS spits errors like

`CS0534 "CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter" does not implement inherited abstract member "TypeAdapter.Read(JsonReader)"`

I've also tried to add the gson.jar file into the libs folder inside the .aar file, but gave me the same compiling errors as described above

So, what should I do next?

Comment: Check this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: It does not solve my problem, it does not talk about the `ReferenceJar` problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.

I had to extract the jar from the .aar and set it as an `EmbeddedJar` and the gson library as `EmbeddedReferenceJar`. Somehow it worked. If someone could explain me why, it would be nice.